# Magento: creating new instances of a helper class each time a loop runs?

Tags: php, magento

I created a custom helper class module which I'm calling thusly:

```
$bench = Mage::helper('benchmark');
// ... do stuff ...
$bench->addBenchmark();
// ... more stuff ...
$bench->logResults();
```

This outputs the results of time benchmarks in an array.

The class is really simple, it basically just adds the current `microtime()` to an array then spits that array out when `logResults()` is called.

The problem is, I have a loop where I'm calling the code above, but instead of logging a "fresh" set of benchmark figures each loop, it's compounding itself and adding to the existing benchmarks array!

I want it to create a new set of benchmarks each time `Mage::helper('benchmark');` is called.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a helper that is not possible, unless you manually flush the content of the array upon calling the `addBenchmark` method.

The problem lies in the following. Within `Mage.php` your requested helper is stored in the registry. Upon next call the exact same helper object will be retrieved from the registry, instead of a new one. It only creates an instance the first time the helper is called.

```
/**
 * Retrieve helper object
 *
 * @param string $name the helper name
 * @return Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
 */
public static function helper($name)
{
    if (strpos($name, '/') === false) {
        $name .= '/data';
    }

    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

You could opt for a model, since `getModel()` returns a new instance each time the factory method is called. Though in my opinion that is a case of bad programming and also hurts you on performance.

I would opt for flushing the latest data upon making a new call to `addBenchmark`. If you want to store all data in the helper for later processing perhaps always return the latest key in the array? Though, thats a matter of choice and flavor, so I will leave that part up to you.

Hopefully this helps you a bit!

Comment: Also, for further explanations, the OP should give these tutorials a read: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Comment: @Tim I'm unable to flush the data because it's designed so that multiple calls will create progressive or compounding benchmarks. I tried to flush it using the __construct method but I see from your post that it's only constructed once. Is there a "better" alternative to using getModel()? I mean, am I going to have to resort to using a plain PHP class?

Comment: @WackGet Helpers are specifically designed to be singletons, you won't be able to instantiate a helper more than once.  Using a Magento model here (via Mage::getModel) is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Add benchmark key and make something like

```
$this->benchmarks[$key]['start'] = microtime(true);
// ... 
$this->benchmarks[$key]['finish'] = microtime(true);
```

so you'll have array of start-finish pairs for every iteration

Why don't you want to use Varien_Profiler?

```
Varien_Profiler::start($_profilerKey);
// ...
Varien_Profiler::stop($_profilerKey);
```

Comment: I actually do this already, only the "finish" is determined by the next time you call addBench. So it's a kind of automatic pair creation. I'll look into Varien_Profiler, thank you. In the meantime is there any way I can get a new instance of my class?

Comment: There is no way to re-instantiate helper with standard magemto api. You can create new instance with `new My_Benchmark_Helper_Data()` but I'm sure this practice will send you to Hell :)

Comment: Could you please tell me why it's poor practice in Magento programming to do this?

Comment: Another module can rewrite your class so you'll be referring to the old version and new functionality will not be used. Factory methods Mage::getModel(), getSingleton(), helper(), etc. are used to take current version of the model, helper, block class.